# How to plot timeseries data where not all dates present and day extends beyond 24h period?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with a timestamp index:

```
                      val
reportTime          
2017-01-07 00:14:00   49
2017-01-07 00:29:00   46
2017-01-07 00:44:00   49
2017-01-07 00:59:00   46
2017-01-07 01:14:00   49
```

The data is in 15 minute intervals for some (not all) Saturdays and Sundays in 2017. For each weekend in the data, I want to plot val from 00:00 until 05:00 on Sunday. I want to put these on a single axis so as to allow for comparison. My  attempt is as follows:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1)
df['val'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).plot(ax=ax)
```

There are two problems here:

1. The data is grouped on a daily basis, rather than by Saturday +5 hours.
2. Since only some Saturdays are present I get a `TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot` error

How do I resolve these?

Comment: Maybe a useless comment here:

1. Can't you use a custom `freq` such as `1D15T` for your first point and use an anchored offset of 5 hours?  2. Did you read the complete doc about Date functionality that contains many (subtle ?) ways to deal with dates ? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases